# Import on database MySQL XML file create with an dataset in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, xml

I need import in table on database MySQL this file XML create with an dataset in c# :

[image]

And I have tried the [LOAD DATA syntax method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\public\\text.xml' 
INTO TABLE `tbl_mysql` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '</Table>' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

But I have this error:

```
[Err] 1261 - Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns
```

Anybody know how can I resolve do this?

Can you suggest?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html. `LOAD DATA` is for CSV

Comment: Thank you, for closed this question?